# How can I play sound from my MIDI keyboard through computer in Rosegarden instead of it coming out of keyboard?

Tags: jack, audio-jack, rosegarden

I have a Yamaha standard keyboard and I would like to get it working with it producing sound through my computer (in my headphones) instead of it coming straight out of the keyboard. I have managed to get **Rosegarden** to record music with the keyboard and as such, is producing sound that I can hear, but it is coming out of the keyboard, not my computer.

I have `Qjackctl` installed if that is any help but has been frustrating to have to switch having my headphones on and off between listening to the keyboard through their in-built speakers, instead of my computers.

I'll reiterate - I can produce sound - I just need it through my computer where I can play keys and hear the music as well as produce and hear recorded playback all through the computer.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the keyboard connected to the PC? You need a working MIDI connection between the two in order to control the PC with the keyboard, either through a USB-MIDI connector or a MIDI plug connected to a soundcard that has that kind of input.

Comment: It does work - i have sound playing and recording the midi through rosegarden but the output sound is coming through the keyboard speakers and i want it coming through my pc. Is that possible to do by changing the settings in rosegarden?

Comment: Is there anything else? Please??

Comment: I have read that you can move sound to pulseaudio, or you can use a soundfont with q synth. Are these viable soultion - i don't want to break what is already working.

Comment: I don't know Rosegarden so I can't help much more. From what I see it should be possible to assign sounds that are played back to the notes, then it would just be a matter of configuration. I'm also not sure I understand what you want to do. Do you want to play sounds other than those of your keyboard from your PC, or do you want to have the sounds of your keyboard on your PC?

Comment: I want to stream sound from my keyboard and record it in realtime through my computer into my earphones

Comment: If you want to record sounds on your PC you need to connect the audio outputs of your keyboard to the PC. For that you need a soundcard with audio inputs which works with Linux.